# Transferring Noticing Script from arcpy.mapping to arcpy.mp

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, layers

I am trying to reconfigure a script I have been using in ArcMap into ArcGIS Pro and have discovered the whole arcpy.mapping vs arcpy.mp. I am stuck on a section that is trying to list layers.

Here is the original script under arcpy.mapping

```
# Get the map document, data frame, and layers
# arcpy.AddMessage("MXD Path: " + mxd_file)
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
    layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
    for l in layers:
        if l.name == "Subject Property":
            subject_layer = l
        elif l.name == "Zoning":
            zoning_layer = l
        elif l.name == "General Plan":
            gp_layer = l
        elif l.name == "Basemap":
            baselayer = l

Here is my attempt to update it: 

 # Get the map document, data frame, and layers
 # arcpy.AddMessage("MXD Path: " + mxd_file)
    aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("Current")
    df = aprx.listMaps("Map")[0]
    for l in df.listLayers():
        if lyr.name == "Subject Property":
            subject_layer = l
        elif lyr.name == "Zoning":
            zoning_layer = l
        elif lyr.name == "General Plan":
            gp_layer = l
        elif lyr.name == "Basemap":
            baselayer = l


This is the error I am getting:

public_notice working
=====================
Parameters

Project Address     2600 W TAYLORSVILLE BLVD
Parcel IDs     21094510720000
Noticing Distance     300 Feet
Output Folder     N:\GIS\Projects\Public Notice
CSV Out     N:\GIS\Projects\Public Notice\Mailing_Labels.csv
Zoning Out     
GP Out     
Site Out     
Vicinity Out     
Messages Out     Verifying Parcel ID(s)...
Creating mailing list...
Writing CSV...
Setting up mxd for mapping...
list index out of range
=====================
Messages

Start Time: Monday, June 13, 2022 4:27:25 PM
Verifying Parcel ID(s)...
Creating mailing list...
Writing CSV...
Setting up mxd for mapping...
PYTHON ERRORS:
Traceback info:
  File "C:\Users\kkerdolff\Desktop\public_notice_maps_work.py", line 118, in <module>

Error Info:
list index out of range

ArcPy ERRORS:


Failed script public_notice working...
Failed to execute (PublicNotice1).
Failed at Monday, June 13, 2022 4:27:34 PM (Elapsed Time: 9.32 seconds)
```

Comment: What happens when you run the code that you have presented?  I would expect that you are seeing an error when you try to use the `lyr` before setting it.

Comment: Your for loop `for l in df.listLayers()` has `l` for layers but you then erroneously call it `lyr` in the if statements.